# What is this notation for dimensions: 2-11/16" x 3-13/16"

Tags: playing-cards

I am looking for dividers to order a card collection. I find some on a website but I really don't understand the dimensions: 2-11/16" x 3-13/16".

Is it (2*11/16)" x (3*13/16)"? It would be rather complicated...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Given the size of a playing card, I would imagine that *2-11/16"* means *two and eleven sixteenths of an inch*, i.e. *2.6875"*. How much simpler things would be if everyone switched to the metric system...!

Comment: @AndyT, I don't see how 68-21/80 mm would be any better, or did you mean "decimal notation" when you said "metric"?

Comment: @ikegami - yes and no. I do mean that things would be simpler in decimal notation. But using sixteenths of an inch is very common in imperial (or "US units"). Because the metric system is based on powers, it lends itself incredibly well to decimal notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"` in [`2-11/16"`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2-11%2F16%22) denotes inches. The number of inches is written using a common notation for representing improper fractions using only ASCII characters. The represented fraction is

[image: 2-11/16]

`2-11/16"` means "two inches and eleven-sixteenth", so the number of inches is actually 2+(11/16) = (2*16+11)/16 = 2.6875, or about 68.3 mm.

Similarly, 3-13/16" means 3.8125 inches, or about 96.8 mm.

Answer (score 3):

2-11/16" x 3-13/16" means 2 and 11/16 inches by 3 and 13/16 inches, or 2.6875 inches x 3.8125 inches. This works out to be about 68.2625mm x 96.8375mm. For reference Magic cards are about 63mm x 88mm.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's really not an intuitive notation! A "-" with the meaning of a "+"...

Comment: @Zach In this context the '-' is just being used as a separator, so you don't think it is 211/16. It isn't meant to be a mathematical symbol.

Comment: I understand. I find it a poor choice of separator